# Midori webapp mode doesn't use cookies

Tags: browser, webapps, midori, cookie

Is there any known workarounds for getting midori to remember the cookies? I only ask because for me the ubuntu-browser app is currently broken (even when I open a link and it loads, all I get is white space).

I am trying to use midori to open gmail and other sites in their own windows, but midori completely sandboxes the webapp, requiring login each time I launch the app, even if I have a cookie from gmail.

Perhaps a way to just make certain cookies global?

Comment: That does not sound like a problem with cookies =)

Comment: see the edit, sorry I am extremely forgetful

Answer (score -1):

Cookies are managed in

Preferences -> Privacy tab

[image]

Your description of the problems sounds unrelated to cookies though.

Comment: yeah, I am like 90% sure that this is a problem with midori sandboxing webapps